# Javascript: Execute a function for every 3 seconds for One minute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to execute a function for every 3 sec upto 1 minutes. This should be called when a user focus on the input box.

I have tried by Googling but most of them come-up with setInterval  function. I knew that the setInterval can be used to call a function for certain time interval. But i need to stop that if the time reaches 1 min.

Please suggest me on this.

Comment: Call clearInterval after being called for twenty times

Comment: Add a counter which you increase every tick, when its over 1 minute stop the interval with `clearInterval`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this on input focus of textbox:

```
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
var interval = setInterval(function(){
if(new Date().getTime() - startTime > 60000){
    clearInterval(interval);
    return;
}
//do whatever here..
}, 3000);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E2Jd8/)**

**Demo Code:**

```
$('input').one('focus',function(){
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
var interval = setInterval(function(){
if(new Date().getTime() - startTime > 60000){
  clearInterval(interval);
  alert('interval cleared');
return;}console.log('test')}, 3000);})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this -

```
var time = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    // do your stuf
    time += 3000;
    if(time >= (1000*60)){ // one minute
      clearInterval(interval);
    } 
},3000);
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/E2Jd8/1/)**